# Identifiable as generic and func parameter

Tags: swift, generics, identifiable

Hello I want to build something like below:

```
protocol BaseEntity: Identifiable {
    var id: UUID { get set }
}
```

```
protocol DataStore {
    associatedtype T: BaseEntity
    
    typealias CompleteHandler<T> = ((Result<T, Error>) -> Void)

    func read(with id: T.ID, completion: CompleteHandler<T>)
}
```

but in concrete implementation I want to make use of the `UUID` that was defined in the `BaseEntity` protocol:

```
class Storage<Entity: BaseEntity>: DataStore {
    func read(with id: Entity.ID, completion: CompleteHandler<Entity>) {
        // here, how to use that id as a UUID?
    }
}
```

I don't know how to do it really, to define that there must be an object conforming to `BaseEntity` and would like to use that `UUID` `id` property in the concrete implementation.
I don't want to do it like:

```
func read(with id: Entity.ID, completion: CompleteHandler<Entity>) {
    guard let uuid = id as? UUID else {
        return
    }
        
    // more code goes here...
}
```

How I should do it?

Comment: What is `Entity.ID`? I don't see how that's defined or how it could possibly compile.

Comment: Hello @matt `Entity` is just like a `T` on a generic constraint.

Comment: Should I just do that in concrete implementation?: `class JSONStorage<Entity: BaseEntity>: DataStore where Entity.ID == UUID {`

Comment: You're trying to conform the parameter `id` to a `Entity.ID` type.  That type doesn't exist (i.e. isn't defined in your `BaseEntity` class).  Do you want to just use 'BaseEntity` as the parameter type and then access its `id` parameter?

Comment: Sorry, the proposed code is too nonsensical for me to guess what you're _really_ trying to do. You have all these `.ID` which seems to imply that these things have a subtype called `ID`. But I don't see anything that has such a type. For example, if a BaseEntity had an associated type called `ID` this would make more sense. But it doesn't.

Comment: `ID` is an `associatedtype` in the `Identifiable` protocol as far as I know.

Comment: yes the `Entity.ID` comes from `Identifable` protocol https://developer.apple.com/documentation/Swift/Identifiable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, basically the lack of any concrete type in this implementation is what troubles the compiler to figure out the `Entity.ID` type.

This can be shown by not using a generic `Entity` type in your `Storage` implementation, like this:

```
struct MyEntity: BaseEntity {
    var id: UUID
}

class Storage: DataStore {
    func read(with id: MyEntity.ID, completion: CompleteHandler<MyEntity>) {
        print(id.uuidString) // <- `id` is of `UUID` type
    }
}
```

**Solution 1:** To help the compiler understand the `Entity.ID` type, you can conditionally conform to the `DataStore` protocol, by stating that `Entity.ID` will always be of `UUID` type (which is actually what you want in your implementation):

```
class Storage<Entity: BaseEntity>: DataStore where Entity.ID == UUID {
    func read(with id: Entity.ID, completion: CompleteHandler<Entity>) {
        print(id.uuidString) // again this line passes compilation
    }
}
```

**Solution 2:** Even better, you can conditional constraint your `BaseEntity` protocol by stating that `ID` will always be of `UUID` type. That way you do not need to change your `Storage` implementation:

```
protocol BaseEntity: Identifiable where ID == UUID {}
// or using the following which is also the same
protocol BaseEntity: Identifiable<UUID> {}

class Storage<Entity: BaseEntity>: DataStore {
    func read(with id: Entity.ID, completion: CompleteHandler<Entity>) {
        print(id.uuidString) // again this line passes compilation
    }
}
```

**Solution 3:** Another solution, which might be more appropriate in your context, is to convert `BaseEntity` to a class. That way you also do not need to change your `Storage` implementation:

```
class BaseEntity: Identifiable {
    var id: UUID
    
    init(id: UUID) {
        self.id = id
    }
}

class Storage<Entity: BaseEntity>: DataStore {
    func read(with id: Entity.ID, completion: CompleteHandler<Entity>) {
        print(id.uuidString) // again this line passes compilation
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you! I have found that Solution #1 works ok for me, but your solution #2 is even better! :) thanks again.